# Search Refiner by Organization Unit

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, people-picker, people-search, refiner

I want to filter my users (people) in a search by the Organization Unit. I'm not finding the field in the refiner webpart.

It is SharePoint Online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the mapped property to the organization unit.
In Search Settings> Search Schema> there will be many properties under people category.From that find the one matching your requirement and then use the mapped property in your refiner webpart.

[image]